# NFS configuration for write-once read-many access

Tags: file-permissions, nfs

Is there a way to replicate the write-once read-many capability of NetApp's SnapLock using a standard Linux NFS server?

I've considered using inotify to chmod files as they're written to the server, but is there a simple way to do this, or a way that would also allow anonymous writes? (All the NFS clients are on a secure network, so that would save extra client-side configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "can I do what SnapLock does without NetApp storage", the answer is "no". NetApp SnapLock uses specific capabilities of the NetApp WAFL file system, as well as a tamper-proof compliance clock that prevents spoofing the server system time (to set the time ahead so you can delete something that isn't yet supposed to expire).

If you mean "can I use NFS commands to lock down files on a NetApp SnapLock volume", the answer is "yes". The SnapLock capabilities are designed to be leveraged with NFS and CIFS file commands.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple write-once read-many configuration for a Linux volume or NFS share... so that from the PoV of the NFS client, you can write, read, but not delete or overwrite. SnapLock goes beyond that, and is worth the investment if you need the compliance capabilities.